# Creating a j2me time triggered application

Tags: java, java-me

Im trying to create a time invoked J2ME application, one that doesn't require the user to start it manually but when some event happens it is triggered like a phone alarm or reminder

Answer (score 1):

try doing it via push registry 
these links will help you 
   [Push Registry](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/PushRegistry) , [Push Registry Java Doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156665.html)

Comment: Thanks, I found some way to work with Push Registry but my main is to create an app that detects a certain date and when it reaches that date it automatically sends an sms, for birthday wishes to be precise, is this possible using PushRegistry?

Comment: Actually a application can be started at the scheduled time but due to Java Permissions it will always ask user , whether he wants to run the application or not . So it requires user interaction at that time, it can't be done automatically.